# python setup.py install - already installed a package, why is it searching pypi to install it?

Tags: python, easy-install, python-pbr

I'm trying to install linecache2, which has a pre-requisite of pbr.

I went to pypi, and installed pbr by downloading and running setup.py build since I'm behind a firewall:

```
    cd   C:\Users\<user_name>\Downloads\pbr-1.5.0\pbr-1.5.0
    python setup.py build
```

Then I went to linecache, and tried to install it using the same method:

```
    cd C:\Users\<user_name>\Downloads\linecache2-1.0.0\linecache2-1.0.0
    python setup.py build
```

However, it outputs:

```
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pbr/: timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pbr' (maybe misspelled?)
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for pbr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    pbr=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 111, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 268, in __init__
    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 830, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1075, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1087, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 623, in easy_install
    raise DistutilsError(msg)
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pbr')
```

Since I already have pbr, why is it trying to go look for pbr?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just built `pbr`, you should install it:

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: yep, somehow I forgot that step :(

Comment: Sure, need to wait for a timer :P